# how to emulate pressing home button in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, keyboard-shortcuts

In android emulator as I understand you can emulate most of the functionality of regular phone, back is emulated by ESC , what is shortcut for pressing home button in android emulator.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Did you try the `Home` key on your keyboard?

[image]

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

Comment: That link no longer seems to have any info about keyboard shortcuts(I'm guessing Google moved docs around which they seem to do a lot). The correct Google Doc now appears to be developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html, but I'll post an answer with all the shortcuts listed here so we actually have the data here.

Comment: Home Key is FN + left_arrow on Macbook keyboards

Comment: @Gabe that link works just fine for me; it simply redirects to http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html. At any rate, if there's a broken link, you should just edit the answer instead of posting a separate one.

Answer (score 36):

From [developer android](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Emulated Device Key                      |              Keyboard Key           |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Home                                     |   HOME (FN + left_arrow on Macbooks)|  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Menu (left softkey)                      |          F2 or Page-up button       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Star (right softkey)                     |         Shift-F2 or Page Down       |  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Back                                     |                  ESC                | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Call/dial button                         |                   F3                |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Hangup/end call button                   |                   F4                |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Search                                   |                   F5                |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Power button                             |                   F7                |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Audio volume up button                   |        KEYPAD_PLUS, Ctrl-F5         |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Audio volume down button                 |       KEYPAD_MINUS, Ctrl-F6         |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Camera button                            |       Ctrl-KEYPAD_5, Ctrl-F3        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Switch to previous layout orientation    |         KEYPAD_7, Ctrl-F11          |
|(for example,portrait,landscape)          |                                     | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Switch to next layout orientation        |         KEYPAD_9, Ctrl-F12          |
|(for example,portrait,landscape)          |                                     |  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Toggle cell networking on/off             |                   F8                |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Toggle code profiling                    | F9 (only with -trace startup option)|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Toggle fullscreen mode                   |               Alt-Enter             |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Toggle trackball mode                    |                  F6                 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Enter trackball mode temporarily         |                Delete               |
|(while key is pressed)                    |                                     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| DPad left/up/right/down                  |             KEYPAD_4/8/6/2          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| DPad center click                        |               KEYPAD_5              |  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Onion alpha increase/decrease            |KEYPAD_MULTIPLY(*) / KEYPAD_DIVIDE(/)|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I was also wondering how to get to the task switcher, which for some reason isn't listed in their keymapping table. I found holding the Home key down for a second gets me to the task switcher, but YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

The keyboard Home button. The list of keyboard shortcuts is available [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#controlling).

Answer (score 2):

The keyboard shortcut changed in new version, Press **F1** in emulator, to get complete shortcuts. Android API_25+

Answer (score 0):

For Android Emulator in JavaScript using Webdriver.io:

```
await driver.pressKeyCode(3)
// This is the keyCode for the home btn
```